# Why does this code not recognize next text (list, index)?

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to code to shows text that i want.

this is the sample of text as follow and it's css file for html5.

```
.table0 {
         border-spacing:0;
}

.tr1 {
      :176.00pt;
}

.table4 {
         border-spacing:0;
}
```

and this is what i am coding so far as follow.

```
with open("path\\file.css","r", encoding='utf-8') as f :
    lines = f.readlines()
    n = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(lines[:-1]):
        table = line.split('.')[-1].split(' {')[0]

        if table == 'table'+ str(n) :
            print(table)
            n = n + 1
```

this shows only table0 and  i don't know why it misses table4. which part is wrong ?

Thanks have a great day.

Comment: ah i'm sorry. i add n = n + 1

Comment: becasue now `n` only reaches `1`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding `table0`, `n` goes up to 1 and your check is equivalent to

```
if table == 'table1':
```

Comment: I found something if tha table number goes up to 1, my code shows what i want well. but in this case table number does not go up to 1...how can it catch all table regardless going up to 1?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like you basically just want to match any line that has a CSS class of .table<n>? If so, the following regex might be a better bet: https://regex101.com/r/nyAdax/1

Comment: Thanks for advice. i would have to find other solution.